# Nested fixed element cannot be bigger than parent on iOs only

Tags: ios, css, z-index, fixed

My issue only happens on **iOs** (on both Safari and Opera), works fine in Chrome, Firefox and even Opera on Windows and Android.

I have the following situation:

```
<div class="flex-box-parent">
    <div class="group01">
        <div class="fixed-element">
            This element has a position: fixed and z-index: 100
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group02">
        On iOS, fixed-element does not cover this part
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the fixed element to appear above everything else on my website, as it is a modal with a full-screen backdrop.
Unfortunately, all the content of `fixed-element` that is bigger than `group01`is not displayed.

Neither `group01` or `group02` have a `z-index` specified. It works perfectly fine on Windows/Android, but on iOS, `group02` is always above.

**CSS**

```
.flex-box-parent{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.fixed-element{
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.group01{
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

.group02{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
```

**MORE INFO #1**

As a test, I removed every single reference to `z-index` in my css, except for the `fixed-element`. Still not working on iOs (working on everything else)

**MORE INFO #2**

It seems the problem is that `fixed-element` cannot go outside the border of its parent on iOS.
It seemed to me that `group02` was above fixed-element, but in fact, `fixed-element` simply cannot go full screen if it means getting bigger than `group01`. I am still looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: show us the CSS

Comment: Added the CSS (just removed stuff like font-size, margins or paddings)

Answer (score 0):

In html you shared div tag is not closed for class `.fixed-element`. Please fix that and check

Comment: It is only a mistake in the code that I copied here. I fixed it in the example but it is not my real code :)

Comment: i have created fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9mfjrxdz/13/ check it. When div tag is not closed the second div appears above. When div is closed second div is not appearing above https://jsfiddle.net/9mfjrxdz/12/

Comment: after i saw the code in jsfiddle, i think the problem is with the rgba is not supported in all safari version checkith" link https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

Comment: i purposely added rgba to show the div when it is closed properly

Comment: and why you re using flex is not support for all browsers maybe the problem because of the flex try to changed

Comment: I am not using flex. I just copied the css provided in question. I only added rgba

Comment: It seems to work with iOs on the jsfiddle, but definitely not working on my website. No idea what could be the source of the issue. Any general knowledge of what could cause this?